# Django : Manipulating a form's csv file input

Tags: python, django, forms, csv

Issue :- I get an empty `rows` and `header` in my custom function. Not able to find the reason.

Backdrop of the issue:-
I'm working on a django page/form that should take a submitted csv file, and if the `'type'` field in the form is checked, it will check if the provided csv has a particular set of columns.

Note, all the classes below are in a single module (validations.py). And the csv file which i input is also proper, with rows and headers.

Below is just a part of a task where i get the issue.. (And no dependencies, at least for the issue).

```
class ReportTypeValidator:
    def __init__(self, config_form, brand_form_set):
        self.config_form = config_form
        self.brand_form_set = brand_form_set

    def check(self):
        is_checked = self.config_form.cleaned_data['type']
        if is_checked:
            self.REVIEW_FILE_COLUMNS_TYPE = REVIEW_FILE_COLUMNS+['Report_Type']
            files = self._get_brand_files(self.brand_form_set)
            print('%%%%%%%%%%%%%')
            print(files)
            for file in files:
                rows, header = FieldFileCsvHelper().read_csv_file(file)
                print('==========')
                print(rows)
                print(header)
                print(file)
                missing_columns = get_missing_columns(header, self.REVIEW_FILE_COLUMNS_TYPE)

                if missing_columns:
                    message = self.message.format(missing_columns=', '.join(missing_columns))
                    raise ValidationError(
                        message,
                        code=self.code,)

        else:
            pass

    def _get_brand_files(self, brand_form_set):
        file_list = []
        for index, brand_form in enumerate(brand_form_set):
            file =brand_form.files[f'form-{index}-review_file']
            file_list.append(file)
            print('@@@@@@@@@@@@@')            
            print(file_list)
        return file_list
```

Before I show further details, please see the django terminal during the above function execution. I added print statements to see the files. The problem is I get an empty row and header.

```
django_1        |  @@@@@@@@@@@@@
django_1        | [<InMemoryUploadedFile: 500_reviews_withoutType.csv (text/csv)>]
django_1        |  %%%%%%%%%%%%%
django_1        | [<InMemoryUploadedFile: 500_reviews_withoutType.csv (text/csv)>]
django_1        |  ==========
django_1        | []
django_1        | None
django_1        | 500_reviews_withoutType.csv
```

The `FieldFileCsvHelper` class :-

```
class FieldFileCsvHelper:
    def read_csv_file(self, field_file: FieldFile):
        dict_reader = self._get_dict_reader(field_file)
        rows = list(dict_reader)
        header = self._get_csv_header(dict_reader)
        return rows, header
```

Below function (which is proper) is the one that generates the error as we're passing an empty header argument while calling it.

```
def get_missing_columns(header: List[str], mandatory_columns: List[str]) -> List[str]:
    missing_columns = []
    for column in mandatory_columns:
        if column not in header:
            missing_columns.append(column)
    return missing_columns
```

The error (due to empty header):

```
django_1        |   File "/app/app1/validators.py", line 83, in check
django_1        |     missing_columns = get_missing_columns(header, self.REVIEW_FILE_COLUMNS_TYPE)
django_1        |   File "/app/app1/validators.py", line 150, in get_missing_columns
django_1        |     if column not in header:
django_1        | TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

Where i'm I missing in getting the `header` properly?

Let me know if i need to add more details.

Comment: `FieldFileCsvHelper().read_csv_file` is not returning what you expect it to. Can you add this method

Comment: @IainShelvington I've already added this method

Answer (score 0):

Finally, found the reason. The reason why no headers were returned is due to cursor/iterable being at the end of the FieldFile.

i.e if the FieldFile was read by any other function previously, then to go through it again, please make sure you set `field_file.seek(0)`. In my case I added it in the `FieldFileCsvHelper` function, and it worked. `header` values are now being pulled from the csv.

```
class FieldFileCsvHelper:
    def read_csv_file(self, field_file: FieldFile):
        field_file.seek(0)                             # Added this line
        dict_reader = self._get_dict_reader(field_file)
        rows = list(dict_reader)
        header = self._get_csv_header(dict_reader)
        return rows, header
```